# Wordpress API in Angular 8. ERROR TypeError: "_co.item is undefined"

Tags: angular, wordpress, api

Here's my situation: I'm working with Wordpress API in a XAMMP local server as backend with Angular 8 frontend.
When I request all the posts, it works, but when I request about only one post, to show it into the component, I got this error:

> ERROR TypeError: "_co.item is undefined"
>
> View_PostsDetailComponent_0 PostsDetailComponent.html:5

Here is PostDetailComponent.html

```
<app-private-nav>
    <div class="page-wrapper" id="main">
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px" >
                <h1 [innerHTML]="item.title.rendered"></h1>
                <div [innerHTML]="item.content.rendered"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</app-private-nav>
```

I´m not using a model, but it suposed to work anyway.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PostsService } from './../posts.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts-detail',
  templateUrl: './posts-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts-detail.component.scss']
})


export class PostsDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  item: any;
  id: number;
  
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public dataService: PostsService) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.url.subscribe(u => {
      this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    });

    this.dataService.getPostByID(this.id).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.item = data;
    });
  }
```

I'm using this url for the Wordpress API

> wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/[ID]?_embed

And here is the PostService:

```
export class PostsService {
     item: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
 
  getPostByID(id: number): any {
    if (this.item) {
      return of(this.item);
    } else {
      return this.http.get(ENDPOINT_URL + 'wp/v2/posts' + `/${id}` + '?_embed').pipe(map(this.processPostDataID, this));
    }
    }

  processPostDataID(data: any) {
    this.item = data;


     return this.item;
      }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item isn't set to anything when the HTML first loads - it takes a small amount of time for the observable to return the item.

You can wrap the item calls with `*ngIf`. This will prevent `"item.title.rendered"` trying to access an undefined object.

```
<app-private-nav>
  <div class="page-wrapper" id="main">
    <div *ngIf="item" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px" >
      <h1 [innerHTML]="item.title.rendered"></h1>
      <div [innerHTML]="item.content.rendered"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-private-nav>
```

You can also use optional chaining to handle individual calls. Optional chaining makes expressions operating on undefined or null objects safe.

```
<app-private-nav>
  <div class="page-wrapper" id="main">
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px" >
      <h1 [innerHTML]="item?.title.rendered"></h1>
      <div [innerHTML]="item?.content.rendered"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-private-nav>
```

Comment: Great. Please set as the accepted answer in that case :)